# Redirect with MVC and HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a website following the MVC-structure from the CodeCourse-youtube series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ.

The folder is structure:

[image]

Now there are three .htaccess-files. One in the "bestil"-folder, one in the "app"-folder and one in the "public"-folder.

"Bestil"-folder .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/
```

"public"-folder .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The .htacess-file in the app folder just block unattempted access. As you can see I tried to mix my MVC-rewrite conditions with the https-which does not work, as all the content I loaded are "mixed", hence .css-files and .js-files are loaded over http.

I am not an expert on .htaccess-writing, therefore I am asking you how to make both .htacess-files proper?

Thanks

Comment: That's not MVC. Or anywhere even close to it.

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see I tried to mix my MVC-rewrite conditions with the https-which does not work, as all the content I loaded are "mixed", hence .css-files and .js-files are loaded over http.

The problem has nothing to do with mod_rewrite.

After the HTML page is loaded over HTTPS, it contains instructions that tell the browser to load the CSS and JS over HTTP.

Even if an attempt to do that would result in a redirect back to HTTPS, the security is already broken, so the browser complains.

You need to change the HTML so that the URLs you specify for JS and CSS using HTTPS from the outset. This is most easily acomplished by using relative URLs instead of absolute URLs.